# How to write a GIF animation to file-like buffer in matplotlib?

Tags: python, file, animation, matplotlib, bytesio

I'm trying to create a GIF animation and pass it as a file-like object to an API, without writing to disk. I was able to do something similar with a PNG image:

```
img = BytesIO(); welcome_image.save(img, 'PNG')
```

However, the save() method for Animation seems to expect just a file name, not a file-like object:

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.save.html

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib uses external programs like `imagemagick` or `ffmpeg` to create the animation. Those are called through a subprocess. They will require a filename to create their output to.

Only very recently the option to use `pillow` for creating gifs was added. With this it would theoretically be possible to do everything in memory, but as it stands this option is not available.

Comment: What do you mean by "animation saves its frame to disk anyways"? Where is that implemented? And with imagemagick you can output to stdout.